# Getting html tags in translated block display

Tags: blocks, i18n-l10n

I created a block and enabled its translation settings.
I followed [this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1252144#comment-6736460)

to add ckeditor at block translation. 
When I view the translated block its shows block contents with html tags.
Eg: If the text is 'thai' then the translated ouptup is "< p >thai< /p >"

Comment: You are getting <p> printed or you are getting it in source of ckeditor? If in source then it is in its behaviour. You need to override its behaviour by editing ckeditor configuraiton.

Comment: I get <p> printed. it converts all the html tag and show them as plain text

Comment: Can you please post screenshot here of ckeditor?

Comment: I do not know exactly what was the problem. In my site 'Aggregate and compress CSS files.' was enable before. I disabled it and flushed the cache, block translation work perfectly fine.

Comment: I think you should rework your last comment into an actual answer (so that you can mark it as accepted, and it no longer shows up as an unanswered question).